# What is the name of a cilinder-like object based on an ellipse instead of a circle?

Tags: geometry

If I project a circle over the Z-axis, I'll get a cilinder.

If I project a square over the Z-axis, I'll get a parallelepiped.

If I project an **ellipse** over the Z-axis, I'll get a... *whatsitsname?*

I can't find the name of this object, and I can't believe it doesn't have one to begin with.

Comment: An *elliptic cylinder*.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCylinder.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29#Other_types_of_cylinders

Comment: Well, that was easy. :-/
Thanks, guys.